# Mobile site: Template switching or domain redirection?

Tags: mobile

When creating a mobile version of your website, is it better to redirect the user to a domain name that is designated as the mobile version or should you just switch templates internally and serve the mobile content on the same domain.

The redirect will cause more loading time but is there some other usability reason for using that approach?

Answer (score 1):

I have developed some mobile web applications. Although my application has mobile detecting and it renders content dinamicaly. I like to have a mobile domain, it is useful and good for SEO. I include a bottom link for changing from desktop to mobile web.

Answer (score 0):

Before answering your question, I suggest you see this [xkcd cartoon](http://xkcd.com/869/).

Now on to your question. Some sites does maintain a seperate domain for smart phones. That is to avoid overloading the phone which probably has a limited bandwidth. So if your site is rich and have lot of animations, then you do not want to serve the same page to smart phones. The problem with this approach is what the cartoon talks about. (this has happened a thousand times for me and my  "smart" phone)

Now if you have a simpler website, that performs well under lower bandwidth, then switching the template is a much better solution. The only usability problem is, if your mobile css is way different from your normal css, this might throw some people off guard. ( after all usability is for computer illiterates and pseudo geeks, a geek will get the information he needs in a dumpster).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Our architecture will actually serve up a completely different html template and css when serving in "mobile" mode.  It basically is a different website for all intents and purposes.  The question really only is, do we serve it under the same domain name abc.com or serve it by redirecting to m.abc.com.  Either way is just as easy to do server side, just wondering if there are any pros/cons client side to each approach.

Answer (score 0):

For search engines (that is, google) it doesn't matter: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/02/making-websites-mobile-friendly.html

And there are really no technical factors that lead to one choice or another.

They each have some benefits.

Same domain:

- redirect not needed
- new features easier to integrate
- less marketing needed

Separating domains:

- more separation of technical concerns
- can market separately
- can migrate to a different machine if traffic requires